# R - Converting two sets of coordinates to Spatial Point Data Frame

Tags: r, gis

I have data with 2 sets of coordinates and other variables.

How can I convert two sets of coordinates into SpatialPoint data frame?

```
From     To      Dist        xFrom    yFrom      xTo       yTo
BARINGO BOMET   1.7019462   35.9659 0.819193    35.3146  -0.753203
BARINGO BONDO   1.9648836   35.9659 0.819193    34.2529  -0.143303
BARINGO BUNGOMA 1.3139522   35.9659 0.819193    34.6606   0.668653
```

I have two sets of coordinates (xFrom,yFrom) and (xTo,yTo) and have tried the below codes which are not working

```
library(sp)

df <- sample[-4:-7]
xy1 <- sample[4:5]
xy2 <- sample[6:7]

SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy1, coords=xy2, data=df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize in advance to mistake your question and do wrong edit.
`coords` should be one `matrix` or `data.frame`, and `nrow(data)` should equal the number of points.

```
xy1.1 <- as.matrix(xy1)
xy2.1 <- as.matrix(xy2)   # rbind(xy1, xy2) doesn't run because of difference colnames.
xy12 <- rbind(xy1.1, xy2.1)
df2 <- rbind(df, df)

SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy12, data = df2)
```

**[Edited]**

you can filter `SpatialPointsDataFrame` data using its `data.frame`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(df, Attribute = rep("from", nrow(df)), ID = 1:nrow(df))
df2 <- data.frame(df, Attribute = rep("to", nrow(df)), ID = 1:nrow(df))
xy12 <- rbind(as.matrix(xy1), as.matrix(xy2))
df12 <- rbind(df1, df2)

SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(xy12, data = df12)
# sort.list <- order(SPDF@data$ID)
# sorted.SPDF <- SPDF[sort.list,]

head(SPDF, n=4)
#            coordinates    From      To     Dist Attribute ID
# 1  (35.9659, 0.819193) BARINGO   BOMET 1.701946      from  1
# 2  (35.9659, 0.819193) BARINGO   BONDO 1.964884      from  2
# 3  (35.9659, 0.819193) BARINGO BUNGOMA 1.313952      from  3
# 4 (35.3146, -0.753203) BARINGO   BOMET 1.701946        to  1

SPDF[SPDF@data$Attribute == "from",]  # only "from"
SPDF[SPDF@data$Attribute == "to",]    # only "to"
# ind1 <- which(SPDF@data$Attribute == "from")

plot(SPDF, col="#00000000")           # a draft to set coordinates
plot(SPDF[SPDF@data$Attribute=="from",], col=2, add=T)
# plot(SPDF[ind1,], col=2, add=T)
plot(SPDF[SPDF@data$Attribute=="to",], col=4, add=T)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. xy12 has combined the two different coordinates into one row. But, I would need those separately for analysis. For example, I need to plot two graphs for "From" and "To".How can I have two sets of coordinates in my spatial data frame?

Comment: @Jessie; It is difficult to archieve perfectly what you want because you want to separate "from" and "to" but data is across the group. `SpatialMultiPointsDataFrame` can contain some groups of points but it need that one group have only one row of data. If you needn't combine all coordinates, you can choice to make two `SpatialPointsDataFrame` ("from" and "to") . (an example plot code if do so; `plot(rbind(fromSPDF, toSPDF), col="#00000000"); plot(fromSPDF, add=T); plot(toSPDF, add=T)`